# DAX Measure to count Rows if relation may not exist

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am looking for a DAX measure to solve the following problem:
Count the number of rows in the dimension table where the Fact table either has no rows or the score is 0.

**Table A (Dimension Table)**

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

**Table B (Fact Table)**

| ID | score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |

**Expected Result**
In this example, I would expect 2, as ID=1 has one row with score=0 and ID=3 as no corresponding row in the Fact Table.

I came up with this measure which gives me the number of rows that have no corresponding row in the fact table, but I am not able to integrate the first condition:
`CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Dimension'), FILTER ('Dimension', ISBLANK ( CALCULATE ( COUNT ('Fact'[id]) ) )))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably much more straightforward methods, but try this **measure** for now:

```
MyMeasure = 
VAR MyTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        Table_A,
        "Not in Table_B", NOT (
            Table_A[ID]
                IN DISTINCT( Table_B[ID] )
        ),
        "Zero Score in Table_B",
            CALCULATE(
                COUNTROWS( Table_B ),
                Table_B[score] = 0
            ) > 0
    )
RETURN
    SUMX(
        MyTable,
        [Not in Table_B] + [Zero Score in Table_B]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
CountID =
VAR ScoreZero =
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( TableB, [score] = 0 ) )
VAR NonExistentIDs =
    COUNTROWS ( EXCEPT ( DISTINCT ( TableA[ID] ), DISTINCT ( TableB[ID] ) ) )
RETURN
    ScoreZero + NonExistentIDs
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are multiple Rows with score=0 for one ID in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This also works, not sure it's a good idea to nest `CALCULATE`:

```
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table_A'), FILTER ('Table_A', ISBLANK ( CALCULATE ( COUNT ('Table_B '[id]) ) ) || CALCULATE(COUNTAX(Filter('Table_B ','Table_B '[score]=0),'Table_B '[id])>=1)))
```